# Range.End not returning Long; going to end of spreadsheet, not stopping at first blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to find the last row number in a column of data:

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = Range("A4").End("xlDown").Row
```

There are no blank cells between data in the A column. I am getting a type mismatch error. When I try to select the last row, I get an object error.

I am using the previous code because this code:

```
Workbooks(JunxureFile).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4", "A" & 
Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
```

did not stop after the first blank cell, and instead copied the entire column (to the max rows Excel allows).

Every example I've seen of Range.End implies it should not be acting this way, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm going to try just using rows.count for now, but I'd like to know what the issue with this code is. How do I change my code for it to work?

**EDIT2:**

I just tried

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = Rows.Count
```

to see that Rows.Count is getting me 1048576, so it's still selecting way too many rows. I'm going to try copy and pasting my data to a different workbook to see if that helps (EDIT3: it did not).

Comment: You don't put quotes around `xlDown` but you should be using `xlUp` anyway: `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I think it is necessary to use xlDown since he wants the last row, not the first, right?

Comment: @Samuel No, the suggested code starts from the very last row of the worksheet going `xlUp` to the last used row. That is a usual practice to find the last used row if there are empty rows in between.

Comment: He says there are no blank cells in between, but makes sense to be safe.

Comment: `Range("A4").Rows.Count` is always `1` because range `A4` has one row if you count them. You should have a look at the first comment here again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Right, oops. I switched to I set a cell value to Rows.Count and it returned 1048576, which is far more rows than I actually have.

Comment: @J.Mill Of course `Rows.Count` obviously gives you the maximum row count of a worksheet. It is the same as `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` which means count the rows of the active sheet. And that's what it does, it counts them, no matter if they are empty or not (because that was not specified). A code always does **precisely** what it says.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ok. This is my first time working in VBA, so I'm still getting used to what everything means and how to reference everything. Thought I saw somewhere that Rows.Count gets you the number of nonempty rows, guess I remembered wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Workbooks(JunxureFile).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4", "A" & Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
```

might fail because you did not specify the correct worksheet for the second range like

```
Workbooks(JunxureFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4", "A" & Workbooks(JunxureFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
```

or in a shorter way

```
With Workbooks(JunxureFile).Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A4", "A" & .Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
End With
```

**Explanation:**
If you use `Range("A4")` without specifying in which worksheet this range is, VBA guesses which sheet you mean and in most cases it is the same like writing `ActiveSheet.Range("A4")` but this might be easily the wrong sheet. So **always** specify which worksheet you mean the range to be in like: `Workbooks(JunxureFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")`

Comment: This is the proper answer - I was having issues getting `xlDown` to work but I wasn't specifying my range.